# Order of product of elements divides l.c.m of order of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G,.)$ be a finite abelian group. Let $a,b\in G$. Then $o(ab)$ divides $\operatorname{lcm}[o(a),o(b)]$.

$Proof$: Let $L=\operatorname{lcm}[o(a),o(b)]$. Also, $o(a)=m, o(b)=n$.
This implies, $m\mid L$, $n\mid L$. Therefore, $L=mk_1 , L=nk_2$ for some integer $k_1 , k_2$.
Now, $(ab)^L=a^L b^L=a^{mk_1} b^{nk_2}=e$. 
This implies $o(ab)\mid \operatorname{lcm}[o(a),o(b)]$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: $(ab)^L=a^Lb^L$ assumes commutativity, which you ain't got in groups in general.

Comment: Also also, note $[(12)(34)](135)=(12345)$.

Comment: $o(ab)$ mean order of a*b.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is also given that G is commutative group.

Comment: For the commutative case, it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the proof is essentially correct **if $G$ is a commutative group**, 
but could be written a bit cleaner:

Let $M$ be the least common multiple of $o(a)$ and $o(b)$. In particular, $o(a) |  M$ and $o(b) | M$ so there exist integers $k_1,k_2$ such that $M = k_1o(a) = k_2o(b)$.

Now (where the first step essentially uses commutativity)

$$(ab)^M = a^M \ast b^M = a^{k_1 o(a)} b^{k_2o(b)} = (a^{o(a)})^{k_1} \ast (b^{o(b)})^{k_2} = e^{k_1} \ast e^{k_2} = e$$

and so the order $o(ab)$ of $ab$ has to divide $M$ by minimality of the order.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking,  how does that follow from Lagrange?

Comment: @ChrisCuster I meant the theorem that $a^n = e$ implies $o(a) | n$. I edited.

Comment: Right.  I'm familiar with that.